# Unable to start Zookeeper Server Process

Tags: apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm trying to start zookeeper server process through ambari in HDP. However, I'm getting error stating that Connection failed: [Errno 111].

I have checked in server logs (/var/log/zookeeper/server.out). It is giving below error. Can someone please help me to understand or resolve issue.

ERROR [ZooKeeperServer@294] - Severe unrecoverable error, exiting
java.io.IOException: No space left on devices.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. You have no free Disk-Space on your Node where Zookeeper is running.

Check it with `df -h` if its a Linux-Server.